I can't connect to the server using retrofit2 + kotlin
I attach the complete files of my attempt to connect to the server with retrofit by logging in to the app. The server returns 3 variables to me and the idea is to display them indicating that I am logged in. In the mainactivity, the edittext and the button are arranged to validate the login (username and password) by giving the button the display of the user and the password as proof that it collected the values ​​that the user entered. The idea is that you then make the query to the server which returns 3 values ​​if the user and password match those saved in the database. If I connect by entering a valid username and password in the code, it returns the information of that user. but obviously I need the information entered by the user to be verified. but I haven't achieved it yet. I leave the code for your suggestions and guidance. MainActivity:
//MainActivity
package com.example.leccion1

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.example.leccion1.ui.theme.Leccion1Theme
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import kotlin.math.log

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Leccion1Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.login)
                    val usuariov =findViewById<EditText>(R.id.usuario)
                    val clavev =findViewById<EditText>(R.id.clave)
                    val botonBuscarv = findViewById<Button>(R.id.boton_buscar)
                    botonBuscarv.setOnClickListener {

                        val mensaje = "Usuarios: ${usuariov.text} y la clave:${clavev.text} "
                        Toast.makeText(this,mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        val intent = Intent(this, pdc::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("usuario", usuariov.text.toString())
                        intent.putExtra("clave", clavev.text.toString())
                        val urlBase="https://myweb/mobile_app/"
                        val rtf = Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(urlBase)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build()
                        val servicio= rtf.create(getApiService::class.java)
                        lifecycleScope.launch {
                            val respuesta_servidor= servicio.getUserById(usuariov.text.toString(),clavev.text.toString())
                            if(respuesta_servidor.isSuccessful){
                            runOnUiThread {
                                if(respuesta_servidor.body()?.usuario == "err"){
                                    val m="Usuario o Clave Incorrectos"
                                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,m,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                }else{//se login y passw correctos
                                    val mensaje_inicio = "Inicio sesion como: ${respuesta_servidor.body()?.nombre} usuario : ${respuesta_servidor.body()?.usuario} y la cedula:${respuesta_servidor.body()?.cedula} "
                                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,mensaje_inicio,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                }

                            }//respuesta del servidor satisfactoria
                            }else{//el server no respondiop
                                Log.e("error retrofit","${respuesta_servidor.code()} - ${respuesta_servidor.message()}")

                            }
                        }




                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    Leccion1Theme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }


now modeling the response which is expected to be 3 variables
package com.example.leccion1
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
data class getModelResponse(
    @SerializedName("nombre")
    var nombre: String,
    @SerializedName("usuario")
    val usuario: String,
    @SerializedName("cedula")
    val cedula: String
)


and the getapiservice that makes the connection is where the app is scratched
package com.example.leccion1

import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Path
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

interface getApiService {
    @GET("get_sesion_ini.php?login={usuario}&password={clave}")
    suspend fun getUserById(
        @Path("usuario") usuario:String,
        @Path("clave") clave:String
    ): Response<getModelResponse>
}

php code sending json
$consulta =  mysqli_query($miconex,$sql) ;
    if($datos_users=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
        $data['usuario'] = $datos_users['login'];
        $data['nombre'] = $datos_users['nombre'];
        $data['cedula'] = $datos_users['cedula'];
    }else{
        $data['usuario'] = 'err';
        $data['nombre'] = 'err';
        $data['cedula'] = 'err';
    }
    
    //returns data as JSON format
    echo json_encode($data);

If you could guide me it would be excellent
try to connect to a server with retrofit2
I expected to receive a response from the server with the data according to the user
but the app doesn't work it hangs
